# How are values stored in memory?

Tags: c, memory, bit

I have written this code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

static int   static_int;
static char  static_char;
static float static_float;
static char *static_pointer;
static double static_double;
static int   static_end;

int main()
{
    printf("static int      =%d\nstatic char        = %c\nstatic float      = %f\nstatic pointer    =0x%x\nstatic doub    le    =%f\n",
    static_int,static_char,static_float,static_pointer,static_double);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("static int      =0x%x\nstatic char      =0x%x\nstatic float     =0x%x\nstatic pointer   =0x%x\nstatic_doub    le    =0x%x\nstatic end       =0x%x\n",
                  &static_int,&static_char,&static_float,&static_pointer,&static_double,&static_end);
    return 0;
}
```

And I get this result:

```
static int      =0
static char     = 
static float    = 0.000000
static pointer  =0x0
static double   =0.000000


static int      =0x804a030
static char     =0x804a034
static float    =0x804a038
static pointer  =0x804a03c
static_double   =0x804a040
static end      =0x804a048
```

I am confused.

First, why does a char hold 4 byte memory (should it only take one?)?

And why does a float only take 4 byte memory? I think it will transform to double automatically. And a double takes 8 bytes.

PS: I use SUSE and GCC.

Comment: When printing addresses as in `printf("...%x...`, a better and correct format specifier is `printf("...%p...`.

Comment: I am a new man here. Can any one explain the downvote?

Comment: NMDV (not my down vote), but your use of "bit" when "byte" implies a  fundamental lack of the basics and therefore why are you concerned about higher level issues like variable location/size.  I thought your bit/byte was an ESL issue and not truly relevant to your question.

Comment: @chux Thanks .  I will pay attention to thoes details.

Comment: The point of providing source code is that people can edit it in their answers (inserting or deleting lines) or copy-paste it at home to show you what the compiler does with either the old or the new version. Numbering lines prevent all these uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **byte** not bit.
2. char holds just one byte, the next variable is stored 4 byte address away because of [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).
3. float taked 4 bytes on most modern systems. It have nothing to do with conversion to double.

Answer (score 2):

> Why char hold 4 bit memory(should it only take one?)?

It doesn't. `char` always is exactly one byte wide, as specified by the C standard. (What makes you think it's 4 bytes long?)

> And . Why float only take 4 bit memory?

I think you mean 4 bytes? No conforming C implementation has 4-bit types (the smallest type is `char` which is at least 8 bits wide). Again, on most modern systems, `float` is a 32-bit (and 4-byte, assuming an 8-bit byte) single precision IEEE-754 floating-point number, and `double` is a 64-bit (8-byte) double-precision IEEE-754 floating-point number.

So `float` is typically 4 bytes long - and the size of a `float` object doesn't change, even if it's implicitly converted to a `double` when passed to a variadic function. In C, function arguments are passed by value, so conversion to `double` essentially means that a **copy** of type `double` of your `float` variable is made (and passed to the function).

---

(But anyway, where did you get the information about the sizes? I don't see you using the `sizeof` operator anywhere...)

Comment: See the output memory address. char hold 4 bit anyway! I just confused . It happened.

Comment: @LidongGuo Again, what makes you think that `char` takes up 4 bytes? it doesn't...

Comment: static char     =0x804a034
static float    =0x804a038

Comment: @LidongGuo That's not the size of the `char`, that's the address of the variable... Did you **really** just downvote my answer?

Comment: @Yeah So I said "char hold 4 bit memory" not "char is 4 bit memory"

Comment: @LidongGuo But it doesn't... The fact that its memory **address** is so high that it needs 4 bytes to express does not mean that it's **size** is 4 bytes wide... Those have absolutely **nothing** to do with each other!

Comment: @LidongGuo The addresses of the variables are 4 bytes apart because the compiler inserts padding between the `char` and `float` variables to allow them both to start on word boundaries.  This is implementation-specific but typically allows for faster access to the variables.

Comment: -1 because...because...well, no freaking clue really. So yeah, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I am too confused by your question. So, I am answering assuming that you really meant **byte** when you meant **bit** in the above questions.

> First.Why char hold 4 bit memory(should it only take one?)?

Nothing in the result shows that char is holding a 4 bytes in the memory. What you actually printed are the addresses at which the variables are stored. Not the sizes. The compiler assigning a 4-byte word to for char doesn't necessarily mean that char is occupying 4 bytes. Char only occupies 1 byte of the assigned 4 byte word and the remaining 3 bytes are padded with zeroes.
If you are talking about the char pointer,  then as you are aware, the pointer stores the address of the char variable it is pointing to. And this address is a unsigned integer  which is 4 bytes in size.

To get the size of the variables use **sizeof** operator

> And . Why float only take 4 bit memory? I think it will transform to double auto ! Ant double take 8 bit!

The size of Float is 4-bytes (on 32-bit systems). So the compiler assigned 4 bytes. The size of double is always twice that of float. So the compiler assigned a 8 byte address space to store the value. I don't understand why you think that float will be transformed to double. The program doesn't require any such auto conversion.

The compiler assigns addresses in 4-byte words because the computer accesses memory one word at a time for efficiency. The general rule is that this 'access length' (which is 4 bytes in this case) must be at least the size of the lowest size primitive data type (which is char - 1 byte length)